# Script to convert a search on a StackExchange site to a Google search of that site

Tags: script, search

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

[image: screenshot of se search to google search]

### About

Adds a `Google` button below the `Search` button on the search page which takes you to a Google search restricted to the current Stack Exchange site but with the same search terms otherwise.

#### License

I hereby release this script into the public domain. Do what you want with it.

#### Download

You can download it directly from github:gist: [Download](https://gist.github.com/gists/4186914/download)

If you are using Firefox with Greasemonkey installed and enabled, you can [install it directly by clicking here](https://gist.github.com/raw/4186914/6b87737aa37e65196d601ab087a4cfeb2f764c9a/ht-se-search-google.user.js).

#### Platform

It's a browser user script so it can be used directly on Google Chrome and opera via their "extensions" menus and pages. On Firefox it requires [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/). So far It's only been tested in Google Chrome on Windows 7.

### Contact

You can contact me, Andrew Dunbar, a.k.a. hippietrail via [the Travel Stack Exchange chat room, "You Are Here"](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/591), or just leave a comment or answer right here in StackApps.

### Code

It's written in heavily [jQuery](http://jquery.com) -ified JavaScript.
Read the code [on github](https://gist.github.com/4186914).
Make a clone of the code on github.